# Is there an inverse Laplace Transform of $-a\cdot e^{-b\cdot x^c}$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Is there an inverse Laplace Transform of $-a\cdot e^{-b\cdot x^c}$,
where $a,b$ and $c$ are constants, in my case its:
$a=-0.9898;
b=0.3511;
c=0.2553$

The property, that the function tends to zero for $x$ tending to $\infty$ is given, so that's why I think there has to be an inverse transformation. But I don't seem to find it.

Does anyone has an idea?
Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**:

Use the Taylor expansion for the exponential function:

$$
e^{-b x^c} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-b x^c)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-b)^k x^{ck}}{k!}
$$

Now, invert each of the parcels in the sum and see if you get something that converges.

Comment: Thanks I will try that tomorrow.